# Controlling the rendering of directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am using `ng-repeat` to render a directive `n` times. I would like to control the rendering of each instance of the directive using some custom logic to spread out the load on the browser (mainly to help older browsers).

Is there a directive like `ng-repeat` that enables me to do this, or do I need to take manual control over their rendering?

Comment: likely some lazy loading directives around but as far as core goes you would need to take control. lso ways to optimize such as one way binding

Comment: you can control them using something like `ng-if`, but yeah it might be a manual process. I am not aware of anything that controls that

Comment: you could have a look at how ionic solved probably similar issues with ng-repeat: http://blog.ionic.io/collection-repeat-iteration-two/ and http://blog.ionic.io/collection-repeat/

Comment: Angular Material has a directive much like ng-repeat (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) that handles lazy loading, etc. for you.